# How to detect a covered polygon by other polygon in same QGIS layer?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

[Identifying overlapping polygons in single layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119625/qgis-identify-overlapping-polygons-in-single-layer)

As described this question there are 3 conditions for two polygon on a same layer.

1. These 2 polygons can have intersection area. (How to detect-Solved)
2. These 2 polygons can have dublicated. (How to detect-Solved)
3. One polygon can cover other polygon. How to detect? (My question)

Layer: QGIS - SHP layer

Comment: If you want to detect *only* fully covered polygons, you can try this process : 1/ compute the intersection of all polygons 2/ merge the resulting (intersection) layer and the original layer 3/ detect duplicated polygons. A fully covered polygon will stay identical after step 1 and thus will appear as duplicated after step 2. I don't know if there's a shorter way.

Comment: I don't really get the difference between #1 and #3.

Comment: ArMoraer : Your way is suitable for 2 polygons or for few polygons. I want to analyze too much polygons at same tame.                                                              wiltomap : In first condition there is a intersection area and polygon doesn't covered fully. Third condition one polygon fully covered by other polygon.

Comment: @Tuna: you're right. I posted another solution that should work, if I understand correctly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise you can use (or install it if needed) the plugin topology checker and add a rule "not overlap" on your layer and it will show you polygons that overlapping. Here more [informations](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html)

Comment: "not overlap" works just for first condition. It doesn't work on third condition. It works for **adjacent** polygons.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I found a way to detect polygons that are fully covered by other polygons. This is a bit complicated and I am surprised there seems to be no other way (I might have missed a plugin), but here it is (home tested) :

1. Dissolve your input polygon layer (Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve). In the field "Dissolve field", choose "-- Dissolve all --". Let's call `diss` the output layer.
2. Apply an inner buffer to `diss` : Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffers. Here's the thing : you have to choose a *small negative* value for "Buffer distance", e.g. -0.0001 (depending on your projection). It is necessary before the next step (it will set the distance tolerance between covered and covering polygons). Let's call `diss_buff` the output layer.
3. Use the "Select by location" tool (Vector > Research Tools). First input layer : choose your original layer. Second input layer : choose `diss_buff`. In the options, select only "Include input features completely within the selection features". Click OK: all (and only) your covered polygons should be selected.
4. (Optional) You can save the selection with "Save As" and select "Save only selected features.

Tested on GQIS 2.8.