# Checking whether shapefile has overlapping polygons?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, overlapping-features

Using QGIS, what is the quickest way to check whether a shapefile has polygons that overlap each other?

I guess I could import it into PostGIS, then see whether:

```
SUM(ST_Area(geom))
```

is the same as:

```
SUM(ST_Area(ST_Union(geom)))
```

But that doesn't feel like it's likely to be the most efficient way to do it, especially since my shapefile has about 40k features.

Any ideas?

Comment: I reduced the scope of this question to prevent it being closed as too broad, and to match the only answer. To ask the same question for another product just ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks - I've opened the same question for PostGIS; https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243565/check-whether-shapefile-has-overlapping-polygons-in-postgis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing what software you are using I can only answer if you use QGIS. Simply running the 'Topology Checker' tool will identify where all overlaps occur in a single layer

Comment: Thanks - how? I've opened the plugin, do I need to add a rule of some kind? I've tried adding one saying that my layer is layer #1 and it "must not overlap", with no layer #2 - is that what you mean? It's running, but is very slow because my layer is large, so I'm not sure what it will find.

Comment: Ah just found this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119625/identifying-overlapping-polygons-in-single-layer-using-qgis

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me because my shapefile is too large... QGIS just stops responding.

Comment: A faster method might be to throw your layer into PostGIS and search for overlaps by their bounding boxes but I'm not entirely sure how to accomplish that