# QGIS: Join attributes by location calculates values wrong

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, summarizing

It seems like I got the same problem which is discussed in [this thread.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312342/join-attributes-by-location-gives-out-wrong-sum) But since it's 2 years old already, there's an easy solution to this by now?

I'm joining a vector layer which contains seperat buildings with values to a grid with the algorithm "join attributes by location (summary)". My "summaries to calculate" option is "sum".
Now my problem is, sometimes the buildings cross the line of a rectangle of the grid (see image). In these cases, the building gets recognized twice and thus the resulting sum of the layer is higher than it should be.
My question is, how can I tell QGIS to put the buildings each only in one grid if they're set in two?
The best solution would be, if the buildings would automatically be set in the square where the most of it is in.

[image]

Comment: Maybe use the centroids of each building as the absolute reference for its location

Comment: Man...you are right, of course, why didn't I think of this? I already had the centroids because I created a heatmap as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create a new layer with the centroids of your builings, using `Geometry by expression` ([see how to do it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)). Then join the centroids.

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit embarassed that I didn't think of this myself since I also already created a heatmap with the same data and thus already had the centroids...thank you very much! Also, I found that I get almost similar results if I use "overlaps" as geometric predicate instead of "intersects".

Comment: Hey, sometimes it takes someone else to look at your project to see the obvious - that happened to me as well. That's why this site is for.